# How to make form handler of checkbox, Python, Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-templates

I have a problem: I want to make checkboxes of each line of table:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>cb</th>
                <th width="150">first_col</th>
                <th>sec_col</th>
                <th width="150">third_col</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
{% for i in list %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="{{i.id}}"></td>
    <td>{{ i.created_date}}</td>
    <td><a href="/{{i}}/"> {{ host }}/{{i}}/ </a></td>
    <td>{{i.number_of_clicks}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
         </tbody>
         </table>
    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="button">Del</button>
</form>
```

And in the `def` I make next in order to check if it works:

```
if 'delete' in request.POST:
    for item in request.POST.getlist('choices'):
        print (item)
```

But it does not print anything... What do i do wrong? Or can you help me to write correct handler of checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check for `request.method == 'POST'` rather than for the submit button name in `request.POST`. Though, that shouldn't be the problem why you don't see anything. From what you posted I don't know what's not working but here's an example that shows how you could achive what you want. It assumes your template is in test.html:

```
# This is just a dummy definition for the type of items you have
# in your list in you use in the template
import collections
Foo = collections.namedtuple('Foo', ['id', 'created_date', 'number_of_clicks'])

def test(request):
    # check if form data is posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # simply return a string that shows the IDs of selected items
        return http.HttpResponse('<br />'.join(request.POST.getlist('choices')))

    else:
        items = [Foo(1,1,1),
                 Foo(2,2,2),
                 Foo(3,3,3)]

        t = loader.get_template('test.html')
        c = RequestContext(request, {
            'list': items,
            'host': 'me.com',
            })

    return http.HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: The OP is testing for the presence of the `delete` *key* in `request.POST`, not for the *value* - so the fact that the value might be empty is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, thanks... I only wanted make sure that request POST have I needed elements.. It has! It works well!